# How to properly find the antiderivative of $\sqrt{x}$ at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I used to write it this way: $$\int \sqrt{x}dx=\int x^{\frac{1}{2}}dx=\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}}+C=\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+C \tag{1}$$
because of the rule: $$\int x^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C, n \neq -1.\tag{2}$$
But now I remember a rule that says I can write $x^{\frac{m}{n}}=\sqrt[n]{x^m}$ only when $x>0$.
So in fact (1) is just finding the antiderivative on $(0,+\infty)$.

What about the antiderivative at $x=0$? I know that it should still be $\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$, or more precisely, $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x^3}+C$ (the same $C$) by taking its derivative but I don't know how to do it the right way.

Comment: 1. The rule is applicable to case $x=0$. 2. In most cases anti-derivative can be extended to boundary point.

Comment: $x$ can be $0$ too, in fact there exists an antiderivative $\forall x\in [0,+\infty)$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Based on what I've learned, you can raise $0$ to a positive integer power only. So the rule is not applicable to $x=0$?

Comment: To any positive real power, not only integer

Comment: @mathlearner check if my answer is what you've asked for

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Oh I think you're right. I think I was taught that way for simplicity. They consider 3 cases where the exponent is a positive integer, is 0 or a negative integer, and is not an integer. In the third case, $x$ should be greater than 0.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is my View Point which might resolve your Issue :**

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}=\sqrt[2]{x^1}$
Let the Integral be $g(x)=(2/3)x^{3/2}+C=(2/3)\sqrt[2]{x^3}+C=(2/3){(\sqrt[2]{x^1})}^3+C$

**We then have $g(x)=(2/3)[f(x)]^3+C$ , thus :

[1] Both $f(x)$ & $g(x)$ have the "SAME" Domain

[2] Both use the "Power of the Square root"

[3] Both "interfere" with that given rule @ $x=0$ !**

If we DO allow $x=0$ for $f(x)$ & we take $f(0)=0$ , then the same applies to $g(x)$ to allow $g(0)=0+C$.

If we DO NOT allow $x=0$ for $f(x)$ & we take Domain to be Positive $x$ , then the same applies to $g(x)$ to take Domain to be Positive $x$.

**Both Cases , we DO have Consistency & we DO NOT get Contradiction.**

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is a bit befuddled, since $\sqrt{x}:=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. They're just different symbols, one modern, one older. They both mean $x=y^2$ for some $y$ given $x$. The integral $$\int \sqrt{x}dx$$ means, for $x=y^2,$ $$\int ydx=\int ydy^2\\=2\int y^2 dy=\frac{2y^3}{3}+C.$$ You can see how being over- or hypertechnical is actually *contrary* to the truth itself, since it doesn't leave any room for *insight*. As an exercise to the reader, be a bit lazy when it comes to domains and ranges, and see if you can't invent some new math.

Answer (score -1):

So you've done most of the job. If we take a look at the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, it is $x\in[0,+\infty)$. So that means that in that set there exists an antiderivative and you found it correctly, it is $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x^3}+C, C\in\mathbb{R}$. If we plug in $x=0$ we find that an antiderivative at that point is $C$.

Comment: [[A]] Assuming the antiderivative is Correct , we can plug in $x=0$ to get that value at that Point : no confusion over that. [[B]] I think OP is asking whether that antiderivative is Correct at $x=0$ , & if Correct , then how to Prove that it is Correct.

Comment: @Prem the part where we define the domain of $f(x)$ shows that there exists an antiderivative at that point.

Comment: Correct , that is essentially what I Answered with more Detail.